# How to replace quote with multiple quotes between parentheses only?

Tags: python

I got a malformed CSV which has quotes inside parentheses, like this:

```
1, 2, 3, "4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9, "10, 11, 12", 13), 14"
```

The desired output is:

```
1, 2, 3, "4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9, ""10, 11, 12"", 13), 14"
```

I can think of replacing first one quote with regex, but how to do this for all quotes inside parentheses?

I can only think of:

```
s = '''1, 2, 3, "4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9, "10, 11, 12", 13), 14"'''
s.replace(re.search(r'\(.*\)', s).group(0), re.search(r'\(.*\)', s).group(0).replace('"', '""'))
```

But I need this efficient enough as the CSV is huge (> 100'000) with only a few malformed lines.

Comment: Are all parantheses in your file balanced i.e. quantity of `(` equals quantity of `)` in each row? Do your data contain nested parantheses for example `1,2,(3,(4,5),6),7` or only flat one (no parantheses inside paranheses)?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

data = '1, 2, 3, "4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9, "10, 11, 12", 13), 14"'

def replace(g):
    return g.group(0).replace('"', '""')

print(re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', replace, data))
```

OUTPUT:

```
1, 2, 3, "4, 5, 6, (7, 8, 9, ""10, 11, 12"", 13), 14"
```